# TextToSpeech change voice

Tags: android

I want to be able to change the voice in the text to speech API such as change the:

Voice from female to male.

Make the voice more clear

Change the speed of the voice

Please can someone let me know if this is possible. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your own conversions for specific strings via `addSpeech()`. There is no documentation for how you can substitute your own text-to-speech engine, though, AFAICT.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the strings are stored in an array how would I go about adding these conversions? Thanks

Comment: @Tommy: Call `addSpeech()` on your `TextToSpeech` object, supplying the string and the audio to play back when that string is encountered. Note that this will only work for your app -- you cannot define these for other applications.