# Android TextToSpeech other library options

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Well, Android official TextToSpeech engine is very simple and easy to implement. I played with it for sometime and it is working exactly as it should.

But one disadvantage of this engine, is it only has one fixed female voice and I must say I am not in love with that voice. And from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815245/android-text-to-speech-male-voice) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127444/texttospeech-change-voice) thread, I came to know there is no way to change the voice.

So my question is, **is there any other TextToSpeech libraries available which can work with android?**

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/freettsandroidi/ and http://freettsandroidi.sourceforge.net/ might be useful.

Comment: Thanks @blessenm let me play with it..

Comment: @blessenm looks like a buggy one... can't install the apk coming with it too..Zero documentation..

Comment: @Downvoter care to comment

Answer (score 3):

Google on 'alterntate android tts engine` gives a few:

- [Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/) (formerly IVONA)
- [Flite TTS](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android/wiki/)
- [SVOX](http://svoxmobilevoices.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Yes, but it also installs it's TTS engine and you can select from Android settings which one to use system-wide. You first need to enable ivona, then select the Speech Engine, then download the voices you want. Free only until beta ends though...

Comment: I am not getting it.. I can install the engine and change the voice. But how can I make my user do that?

Comment: Flite I believe has an iphone version too, I have played with it before.. I didn't know it has an android version..Anyway flite is what I am going to try out first..

Comment: True, with IVONA you would need to have each user download it. Not sure about Flite but it looks more a library kind

Comment: Looks like flite in android is just like a tts engine which user must install to use it in any tts based application..

Comment: SVOX is a collection of tts engines (you can buy different voice's, nothing is free and all have a free trial). It is not a library. So I believe you can only use Android default TextToSpeech api in android and user can buy different voices and add. Our app works in accordance with which voice user choose in settings->Voice input & Output->TextToSpeech settings.

Comment: is that correct, when i want to integrate Ivona SDK for iOS (or Android, doesnt matter) that i have to put in the voice of more then 200 MB in my project? is that not toooo much? i thought the server would handle everything and just gives the feedback with the tts-file.

Comment: Flite TTS looked promising, but I cannot get those wicked C files to work in Android studios.

Comment: SVOX seems to have been purchased by Nuance, but I can't find any more information on it than that.